# Can the same image in HTML have different sources depending on whether the mouse is on it?

Tags: html, css

So here's the problem - i need an image to slightly change when the cursor is hovering on it. However, simply writing something like this in CSS styles:
`img {src="";} img:hover {src="";}`
seems to do nothing. Is there a solution to this problem using only HTML and CSS?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Yup the solution is `{background-image:url("")}`  think so

Comment: You can use js to do that. But please clarify one thing. You have image one and want to change to image 2 when the user hovers it? Or do you want to add an animation to that image?

Comment: Can you add your HTML and CSS code?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please review the [guidelines for posting questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The first point of the guidelines is to do research before posting a new question. Then, the title should be well descriptive of the question you are asking, and the question text must include much more information: you need to introduce well the context, without just posting the error/problem, and you need the right amount of code to let others understand/reproduce your issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `background-image` property and change the `url` on `hover`

```css
img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-image: url("https://pixy.org/src/477/4774988.jpg");
  background-size: 200px 200px;
  ;
}

img:hover {
  background-image: url("https://pixy.org/src/19/193722.jpg");
}
```

```html
<img />
```

Comment: Like the code snippet, didn't realise you could add in answer

Comment: Yup the question and answer have the same formatting functionalities @DeanO'Brien